# Toshiba Excite system crash (and what to do about it)

Tags: android

We've been testing the idea of running a tablet (or anything) as a display for long periods of time, and things are MOSTLY ok, but every couple days it seems like the tablet just crashes.  No power issues, I assume no memory issues.  When I look at it, its obviously powered up, but the screen in blank, and clicking power to wake it up does nothing.  Must long-press the power button to get a hard reboot (no confirm dialog).

Totally confused by what's happening.  Not SURPRISED so much.  I actually would've been a little surprised if this was all trouble free.

However, wondering where I should look for info.  Even if we can't get this to work out, I'd like to send some sort of error report.  I looked in /data/dontpanic, but it was empty.  Any other places for system crash logs?

Comment: What happens if you connect ADB?  I'd be tempted to try to leave a log-collecting app running and writing to a file or something.  Does the device have a setuid reboot you could invoke at 3am every night?

Comment: Hey!  You're probably the best person I know to discuss this with.  I'd need to get root to reboot, although that would absolutely be an option if we knew it was a long running issue.  If overnight reboot solved things, I think we'd be all set. Interesting project, BTW. Not sure what you're doing these days, but may need custom hardware work. If successful, certainly would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured out root cause.  Seems like a strange hardware issue.  Is there a way to remove questions?